# Tables with very small columns

Tags: tables

I want to create a table with *very* small columns with a fixed width (say 1mm). I am trying the code below, but it fails to render these very small columns properly. What can I do to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{1mm}|p{1mm}|p{1mm}}
& & \\
\hline
& & \\
\end{tabular}

The columns should be 1mm wide. Currently they are about 5mm wide.
\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like (the text below is to give you an idea how large the columns are).
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is always some `\tabcolsep` in each cell (that is, a padding to the right and left of the content of the cell), which you probably don't want. You could try setting this to zero using `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}`. The default width of `\tabcolsep` is 6pt, so 12pt are added to the width of each cell, making them about 5mm wide.

Comment: @Jakob This sounds like an x-y-problem.  Can you add a bit more context what you need these small columns for? Are you drawing some kind of grid?